# PHP: comparing two arrays and make one of them compliant with the other

Tags: php

I have created a simple form in HTML + JS that gives the user the possibility to dynamically add users (firstname, lastname) and two checkboxes. The user can fill in a firstname and lastname and check of or more checkboxes next to the name if applicable.
With a click on a button an extra row of firstname and lastname plus the checkboxes appaers. When the user submits this information I retrieve the $_POST information in PHP.

The array in which I receive the information looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Firstname user A [1] => Lastname user A [2] => Checkbox 1 checked [3] => Firstname user B [4] => Lastname user B [5] => Checkbox 2 checked [6] => Firstname user C [7] => Lastname user C [8] => Firstname user D [9] => Lastname user D )
```

In PHP this can be reproduced by:

```
$personen= array ('Firstname user A','Lastname user A','Checkbox 1 checked','Firstname user B','Lastname user B','Checkbox 2 checked', 'Firstname user C','Lastname user C','Firstname user D','Lastname user D' );
```

As you can see when the checkboxes are not checked there are no values stored. When one of the checkboxes is checked the value is captured and in the array. I would be nice if I could fill in the blanks and replace them by zero's.

So I get the array in the format of:

```
A A 1 1 B B C C D D 1 E E
```

The letters standing for a firstname and lastname and the numbers the value of the checkbox. The structure should be firstname, lastname, checkbox, checkbox. Is there a way I can take the values of the given array and put it in a structure like this:

```
A A 1 1 B B 0 0 C C 0 0 D D 0 1 E E 0 0
```

I would be more convenient to read this array of information into a table.
I don't know if my question is understandable. In short: I have an expected structure of information how can I loop trough a given array and push the values into another array so it matches the given structure where "null" values are converted to 0.

Thank you for your help
N0A

Comment: You know there are always two text boxes, right?  So, pull the two text values.  If the next value is not a checkbox, then you know the box wasn't checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send array data via POST (or GET). I assume you can create a `<form>` like this example using your script in JS, just add the index ie `name[index]` on an iteration and you'll get this form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first-name[1]">
    <input type="text" name="last-name[1]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-a[1]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-b[1]" value="1">

    <input type="text" name="first-name[2]">
    <input type="text" name="last-name[2]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-a[2]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-b[2]" value="1">

    <input type="text" name="first-name[3]">
    <input type="text" name="last-name[3]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-a[3]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-b[3]" value="1">

    <input type="text" name="first-name[4]">
    <input type="text" name="last-name[4]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-a[4]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-b[4]" value="1">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And you could do something like this to get the result you want:

```
<?php
    $total_records = count($_POST['first-name'] ?? []);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_records; $i++) {
        echo '<br>';
        echo $_POST['first-name'][$i] . ' ' ;
        echo $_POST['last-name'][$i] . ' ' ;
        echo ($_POST['checkbox-a'][$i] ?? 0) . ' ' ;
        echo ($_POST['checkbox-b'][$i] ?? 0) ;
        echo '<br>';
    }
?>
```

And passing some values, my code returns this content:

[image: result of the php code]

The code needs a refinement and some validation, but I hope you got the idea.

---

**UPDATE:** You asked how to insert the information into a table. You can do something like this:

```
<?php
    $total_records = count($_POST['first-name'] ?? []);
    $table= [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_records; $i++) {
        $table[] = [
            'first-name' => $_POST['first-name'][$i],
            'last-name' => $_POST['last-name'][$i],
            'checkbox-a' => $_POST['checkbox-a'][$i] ?? 0,
            'checkbox-b' => $_POST['checkbox-b'][$i] ?? 0,
        ];
    }
?>
```

And the result will be:

[image: result of the second php code]